# Camel FTP, Move issue

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, ftp-client, camel-ftp

I'm having an SFTP consumer route like:

```
<from uri="sftp://IP:PORT/MyDirectory?username=MyUser&amp;password=MyPasswd&amp;move=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:onlyname}"/>
```

The user has Read/Write permission.

When the component tries to move the file to the "MOVE" directory (that directory its not created) once its complete it fails on:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot create directory: MyDirectory/20170727 (could be because of denied permissions)
```

But if I connect to that SFTP with Filezilla with the same User/Passwd I can create that directory and camel move done files there.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried using stepwise=false, no changes :(

Comment: What is the absolute path to the target directory that you see in FileZilla?

Comment: The absolute path is /, and inside is the directory 'MyDirectory'.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm struggling with the same problem...